# Multiple applications using shared DLLs

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, shared-libraries

I have a few different applications that share some common DLLs. At the moment I am copying each DLL into the application root folder (for each application) and it all works fine.

Obviously this isn't exactly the most efficient way as if I need to make a change in one, I need to redeploy this several times to all the different folders. Ideally I would like the DLLs to be installed into the `Common` folder in the `Program Files` dir and my application just pointing to them. I can do this through my setup application.

However, the issue is, how do I tell my application to look for those DLLs in the common folder and not its root? I currently reference the DLLs by adding the actual Lib projects to the solution and then just adding them from the `Projects` tab. So in order for the application to realise it needs to look in the common do I need to move those files to that folder first and then reference them? I would imagine there must be a neater way than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you deploy it in Global Assembly Cache(GAC)? Its shared between all the installed applications. You can install to GAC using gacutil command.

Comment: @Anuraj: Not really too familar with GAC. Is it easy to update DLLs etc?

Comment: @James : Yes, you can share assemblies, multiple versions of same assembly etc in GAC.Check this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: The OP is talking about unmanaged code, the GAC doesn't apply.

Comment: @James, the "Lib" remark was confuzzling.  Yes, the GAC.  You'd need a manifest with `<dependentAssembly>` and codebase if you want to store them in c:\program files.

Comment: Ok I have added a strong name to all my assemblies. However, one of my 3rd party libs that my lib projects references doesn't have a strong name. How do I go about getting that into the cache?